# Worried about raw eggs, Salmonella, and pasta maker.

Tags: food-safety, equipment, eggs, pasta, safety

I recently got a pasta maker as a gift. The instructions clearly say to NEVER use water on it.

My main concern is the raw egg in the pasta dough. How do I make sure the pasta maker is safe for future use, if I can't wipe it down with soap and water? Obviously, I don't want to give myself or my family Salmonella.

Am I just worrying too much about the raw egg? Is the pasta maker safe to use, even if I only wipe off the dried pasta with a dry cloth; if I never wash it with soap and water?

I'm worrying so much about it, that I'm afraid to use my pasta maker.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: If you aren't planning on eating raw pasta (or cutting yourself with it), and you clearly aren't, what does it matter if the pasta maker harbours some salmonella bacteria? It doesn't survive very long outside of a wet environment.

Comment: Possibly dup of https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19706/how-do-i-clean-a-pasta-maker

Comment: If you are paranoid about Salmonella make your pasta using just Semolina flour and water (no egg needed).

Comment: For cleaning, you can run a piece of kitchen paper through the pasta machine. Still not "water and soap", but at least a bit of cleaning, and certainly beats a rusty pasta machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clean a pasta maker?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19706/how-do-i-clean-a-pasta-maker)

Answer (score 5):

You are worrying too much.  Pasta has been made with egg for hundreds of years.  While the tools may have changed a bit, the process remains the same.  There has been some actual scientific research on the amount of time salmonella can survive on stainless steel and other dry surfaces.  You can google specifics.  It is generally assumed that moist environments are more favorable to growth and sustainability.  So, if you use a wet sponge from your sink, you are more likely to contaminate a surface from that, for example.  In any event, the general consensus is that salmonella survives 1-4 hours on dry surfaces.  One study in the International Journal of Food Microbiol. 2003 Aug 25;85(3):227-36.Survival of foodborne pathogens on stainless steel surfaces and cross-contamination to foods. Kusumaningrum, Riboldi, Hazeleger, and Beumer, transferred salmonella to stainless steel using a kitchen sponge. Salmonella enteritidis was recovered from surfaces for at least 4 days at high contamination levels, but at moderate level, the numbers decreased to the detection limit within 24 h and at low level within 1 h.

Practically speaking, you are going to make pasta then freeze or cook, rendering it safe.  You'll dust off your pasta roller and put it in the closet for a while. It will be safe.  Don't let this keep you from making your own pasta.

Comment: I read once that salmonella contamination comes from the egg surfaces not the interior.  Care should be taken while crashing the eggs! The shell should be disposed off asap and hand washing will prevent spreading.